# Getting Doctrine to use MySQL "FORCE INDEX"

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have a query in Doctrine's DQL that needs to be able to use MySQL's "FORCE INDEX" functionality in order to massively reduce the query time.  Below is what the query basically looks like in plain SQL:

```
SELECT id FROM items FORCE INDEX (best_selling_idx)
WHERE price = ... (etc)
LIMIT 200;
```

I assume I have to extend some Doctrine component to be able to do this with DQL (or is there a way to inject arbitrary SQL into one of Doctrin's queries?).  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I just ran into this same issue in Doctrine 2. Rather than writing a [custom DQL function](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-custom-dql-udfs) or [rewriting as a native query](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-native-queries)... and changed the andWhere()s that were forcing MySQL to use the wrong index to andHaving()s. Just wanted to share that quick and dirty fix should anyone else using Doctrine 2 come across this post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found very few helpful Doctrine_RawSql examples online, so here's what I ended up doing to create my query.

```
$q = new Doctrine_RawSql();
$q->select('{b.id}, {b.description}, {c.description}')
  ->from('table1 b FORCE INDEX(best_selling_idx) INNER JOIN table2 c ON b.c_id = c.id')
  ->addComponent('b', 'Table1 b')
  ->addComponent('c', 'b.Table2 c');
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't like native SQL, you can use the following patch. https://gist.github.com/arnaud-lb/2704404

This patch suggests to create only one custom Walker and set it up as follows

```
$query->setHint(Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, 'UseIndexWalker');
$query->setHint(UseIndexWalker::HINT_USE_INDEX, 'some_index_name');
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a Doctrine SqlWalker extension to apply USE INDEX and FORCE INDEX hints using DQL on top of MySql. Works with both createQuery and createQueryBuilder. You can set different index hints per DQL table aliases.

```
use Ggergo\SqlIndexHintBundle\SqlIndexWalker;
...
$query = ...;
$query->setHint(Query::HINT_CUSTOM_OUTPUT_WALKER, SqlIndexWalker::class);
$query->setHint(SqlIndexWalker::HINT_INDEX, [
    'your_dql_table_alias'           => 'FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (your_composite_index) FORCE INDEX FOR ORDER BY (PRIMARY)',
    'your_another_dql_table_alias'   => 'FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)',
    ...
]);
```

https://github.com/ggergo/SqlIndexHintBundle