# Force index in Doctrine 1.2

Tags: mysql, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I want to use Force index in Doctrine query as like in following mysql query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_one USE INDEX(`force_index_name`);
```

How will I use it in doctrine query like in

```
Doctrine_Core::getTable('table_one)->createQuery()->execute();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Doctrine to use MySQL "FORCE INDEX"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850215/getting-doctrine-to-use-mysql-force-index)

Comment: @Shadow i want to use the keywords in the mentioned Doctrine pattern

Comment: You may need to adapt your wishes to what is actually possible.